# Down unreachable node in akka cluster by http endpoint

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I tried to down the unreachable node by http endpoint according to the page ( https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/cluster-http-management.html#api-definition ) but my attempt was unsuccessful. Could you please provide an answer how to down unreachable node from cluster by http endpoint.

The current cluster state is the next:

Request:

```
 curl  10.1.0.124:8558/cluster/members/
```

Response:

```
{"leader":"akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520","members":[{"node":"akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520","nodeUid":"-7768515516228898368","roles":["dc-default"],"status":"Up"},{"node":"akka://application@10.1.0.133:25520","nodeUid":"2194424415667308056","roles":["dc-default"],"status":"Up"}],"oldest":"akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520","oldestPerRole":{"dc-default":"akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520"},"selfNode":"akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520","unreachable":[{"node":"akka://application@10.1.0.133:25520","observedBy":["akka://application@10.1.0.124:25520"]}]}
```

Tried to down the unreachable node and recieved the error.

Request:

```
curl 10.1.0.124:8558/cluster/members/application@10.1.0.133:25520 -X PUT -d 'operation=DOWN'
```

Response:

```
 A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by asking on lightbend forum https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/down-unreachable-node-by-http/6023/3 . There issue was in default value of akka.management.http.route-providers-read-only property.